# Why so many upvotes for this question?

Tags: discussion

[Do all Non-Hindus remain as Pretas after death?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45560/do-all-non-hindus-remain-as-pretas-after-death)

Why doesn't it fall into the "abysmal posts" category?

It seems to be suggesting that

any soul that takes birth as a non-Hindu will, after the death of the body it inhabits, wander on earth as a ghost, never taking another life form, never being able to attain moksha.

The main purpose of this question is to elicit from upvoters their reasons for upvoting.

Comment: You're touching wrong waters. I tried to show a mirror and got incessantly -minus 7 votes.  The community with all its high rated "elders" seems least bothered with closing these kinds of bigotry incited questions, rather more focused on close voting benign questions. The only thing this post like mine, shall acquire is minuses. Unfortunately. And maybe a bit of trolling and blatant censorship.

Comment: Ultimately, it's not about succeeding and failure.. It's about what one stands for and believes in amd thus can stand by it z whatever the circumstances be. Winning or  LOSING is not the motif. Trying to stand by basic logic of humanism IS.

Comment: You have to individually ask all the users who have upvoted the question. @SK

Comment: Thank you @rickross .  that was very helpful.

Comment: No problem @SK ...

Answer (score 5):

What is abysmal for one, may be matter of fact for another.

Clearly, none of us can PROVE/VERIFY that they wander as ghosts, or go to heaven, or hell (until we ourselves reach that stage).

In that regard, there is zero religious/philosophical/scientific difference between you and that OP.

The only difference is that OP is quoting a scripture which states X.

If you are able to quote a scripture that states Y instead, or X except in cases of Z, feel free to do so.

If you find X abysmal, you are, in essence, finding that scripture abysmal. And it's natural to feel that way because it is natural to confuse righteous punishment with unrighteous tyranny. The only guiding light to differentiate which is which, is Shastras.